# Electrostatic Augmentation of EM Force Vector "Cancellation"

Tags: electrostatics

I have an exp in mind whereby a twisted pair is wound upon an air core cylindrical former, wrapped in mylar and slid within a long aluminum tube. The tube is to be charged with negative HVDC such that the coil thus becomes the "positive" side of a HV capacitor.

Ideally, the charge should migrate to the outer curvature of the tube and produce a zero field within.

One end of the coil receives an audio test frequency while the distal end is shorted through a load resistance to create an opposing current between conductors.

My premise is that this will cause a measurable change in EMF from the coil.

Can anyone please help me understand the electrodynamics implied by this type of configuration so I can decide how to set it up for the best chance of success?

Comment: Consider putting a drawing to help us understand what it is you are thinking of doing.